# How can I run a Node server on the player's machine?

Tags: unity, node.js

I'm making a game with Unity. The game's multiplayer server runs on Node, but it's only run on my own machine. How do I bundle Node to my game's installer to install it on my player's machine?

Comment: You've added the [unity] tag to this question but it is not clear why from the content of your question. Are you using Unity to develop your game and compile the installer?

Comment: @doppelgreener yes.